# Avoiding duplication in Maven

Tags: maven

I've got a pom with a few profiles in.  For one of these profiles I want to add a module of server side test code for querying the database in some javascript integration tests.

I dont want this code to ship as it will be bloat aswell as possibly introducing some security problems.

The current setup we have is that there are basically 2 main profiles, which **specify their own distinct module lists** as well as quite a long list of properties.  We then also have a minification profile which gets run for certain builds.

This works by using the -P flag and supplying multiple: eg `-P firstMainProfile,Minification`

The new profile needs to just add one module but depends on some of the other modules and some properties.  I was hoping I'd just be able to do this:

```
    <profile>
        <id>Test</id>
        <modules>
            <module>TestCode</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

and then just run it after the one which has the modules it depends on. eg

```
-P firstMainProfile,Test,Minification
```

However this doesn't work.  When it tries to build it complains about not being able to find the dependencies.

I could just copy the entire profile and add this extra module in but it going to cause me a maintainance headache and as its an acceptance/integration I want it to be setup exactly the same way as the other one.

Help please!  Is there something I can do with profiles to make this work?  Do I need to do something to the sub pom to list the dependencies? it currently looks like this:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <groupId>something</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>TestCode</artifactId>
```

**Update**

I thought I had this fixed but actually all I've done is push the problem further down the line.  The project has a web module which as I understand it is basically just there to say what goes into the war file.  My new module wasn't going in there until I added it as a dependency of that project.  However now the new module gets built and shipped even if I don't explicitly build it which doesnt make sense to me and is the opposite of what i want.

It appears it is getting stored in my m2 directory when it gets built and so is getting pulled from there even if I dont build it.

So now it seems I need to duplicate the web project to change what gets deployed?  Is there some way of just making a dependency conditional to avoid having to do this?

Comment: You should have some dependencies in your `TestCode` module -- usually the modules it needs in order to run the tests. Maven will allow `TestCode` to transitively use the dependencies of these modules, but you may also need extra dependencies in your `TestCode` module. If you could past your entire pom for `TestCode` and the error you're getting I could help more.

Comment: @EngineerDollery thanks - turns out I was missing something pretty basic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a pretty long series of steps that needed doing.

**Add dependency on other module(s) in the new module**

I think I assumed that IDEA would sort out the dependencies for the project when I added an import to a class in another project.

I needed to add this to my new pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>myOtherProject</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Add meta information about the dependency to parent pom**

I also needed to add a dependency in the parent pom in dependency management which defines the version for the other ones.

**Add 'dependency' to deployment project**

I also then needed to add a dependency to the webapp/war deployment pom that is activated by a particular profile (this seems to be the only way to have conditionality in maven?).

**Avoiding duplication**

Thankfully it appears that the dependencies list is additive so if you do something like this:

```
<dependencies>
    a
    b
    c
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Test</id>

            <dependencies>
                d
            </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you end up with dependencies `a,b,c,d` if you use profile 'test'.  So you don't have to copy paste the whole lot and define 2 profiles to add one more dependency.

I also appears the same additive principal is also at work when you use other lists in maven.

I'm merging the basic set of modules (from 1 profile) and my test one and it seems to figure out the right build order.

My new profile looks like this.

```
    <profile>
        <id>Test</id>

        <modules>
            <module>TestCode</module>
        </modules>

        <properties>
            <environment>test</environment>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

So I just specify the differences (as long as they are additive!).

It took a long time to figure it out but I'm reasonably happy with that solution even if it isn't really clear what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a clear understanding of your issue but I think you don't want to have to copy your `<dependencies>` tag in your Test module because it's very similar to your firstMainProfile module's `<dependencies>` tag?  If that's correct, you should [import dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

> The examples in the previous section describe how to specify managed dependencies through inheritence. However, in larger projects it may be impossible to accomplish this since a project can only inherit from a single parent. To accommodate this, projects can import managed dependencies from other projects. This is accomplished by declaring a pom artifact as a dependency with a scope of "import".

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>B</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>B</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>d</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>a</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>c</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

> Assuming A is the pom defined in the preceding example, the end result would be the same. All of A's managed dependencies would be incorporated into B except for d since it is defined in this pom.

Running with this idea, it may be more straight forward to have your Test module be a child of your firstMainProfile module. That way it will automatically get these dependencies and you don't have to bother with importing.

Comment: I don't really understand the stuff you've posted there - from reading the documentation it seems to just be about sharing version numbers and not actually including the relevant modules?